# How can I pass an input value from component to a state of a class on react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a reactjs application. I have two different components; Storymap and Ranger. The ranger renders an input that I can swipe to get numbers from -70 to 70. I want to pass it to Storymap so I can use it to resize some divs

this is the range code

header.js

```
class Ranger extends Component {
    state = { inputValue: null };
    render() {
        return (
            <Flex layout="row" class="navbar">
                <span style={{ color: "white", fontsize: 15 }}>Statsh</span>

                <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
                    <input type="range" name="" id="range" min="-70" max="70" onScroll={(event) => this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })} />
               
                </div>

            </Flex >

        );
        <StoryMap value={this.state.inputValue} />
    }
};
```

and in the Story map I put:

```
class StoryMap extends React.Component {
    state = { zoomLevel: 0 };
....
.... code }
```

I don't know how to pass the input value which is the range in my case. Thanks to anyone who takes time to review and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Use onChange instead of onScroll event:

```
class Ranger extends Component {
    state = { inputValue: null };
    render() {
        return (
            <Flex layout="row" className="navbar">
                <span style={{ color: "white", fontsize: 15 }}>Statsh</span>

                <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
                    <input type="range" name="" id="range" min="-70" max="70" onChange={(event) => this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })} />

                </div>
                <StoryMap value={this.state.inputValue} />
            </Flex >

        );

    }
};
```

Comment: the problem isn't onchange i think    <StoryMap value={this.state.inputValue} /> is wrong :s passing the value is wrong

Comment: okey i changed it on change but i need to pass the range value a number from -70 to 70 to the stormap class i dont know how to do that

Comment: Ahh and you should wrap in in the .row Flex the <StoryMap>

Comment: thank you peter but how ur sure that storymap contain the value of the range it doesnt work for me

Comment: There are several mode to make sure it contains the prop from a parent component. I would recomend the https://reactjs.org/, and try out this jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/fg5v2Lpm/18/

Answer (score 0):

Just rename `zoomLevel` into `value`. Or use `zoomLevel` instead of a `value` as a prop:

```
<StoryMap value={this.state.inputValue} />
...    
class StoryMap extends React.Component {
  state = { zoomLevel: 0 };
```

You pass `value`, then inside `StoryMap` you use `zoomLevel` - they don't connect.

Comment: `zoomLevel` is a state in StoryMap, and `value` is a prop from Ranger to StoryMap. You dont need to rename, but semantically its better for sure